# @types/hapi__hapi error TS2314: Generic type 'Listener' requires 1 type argument(s)

Tags: typescript, types, yarnpkg, hapi

new to hapi and using version "@hapi/hapi": "^20.1.2" in Typescript. When I yarn add the package "@types/hapi__hapi": "^20.0.6, there is a type mismatch between @types/hapi__hapi and its dependency @types/hapi__podium. And I get the following error:

```
node_modules/@types/hapi__hapi/index.d.ts:254:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'RequestEvents' incorrectly extends interface 'Podium'.
  Types of property 'on' are incompatible.
    Type '{ (criteria: "peek", listener: PeekListener): void; (criteria: "finish" | "disconnect", listener: (data: undefined) => void): void; }' is not assignable to type '<Tcontext extends object = this>(criteria: string | CriteriaObject, listener: Listener<Tcontext>, context?: Tcontext) => this'.
      Types of parameters 'listener' and 'listener' are incompatible.
        Types of parameters 'tags' and 'encoding' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ [tag: string]: true; }'.

254 export interface RequestEvents extends Podium {
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/hapi__hapi/index.d.ts:514:32 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Boom' as a type.

514     response: ResponseObject | Boom;
                                   ~~~~

node_modules/@types/hapi__hapi/index.d.ts:627:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'ResponseEvents' incorrectly extends interface 'Podium'.
  Types of property 'on' are incompatible.
    Type '{ (criteria: "peek", listener: PeekListener): void; (criteria: "finish", listener: (data: undefined) => void): void; }' is not assignable to type '<Tcontext extends object = this>(criteria: string | CriteriaObject, listener: Listener<Tcontext>, context?: Tcontext) => this'.
      Types of parameters 'listener' and 'listener' are incompatible.
        Types of parameters 'tags' and 'encoding' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ [tag: string]: true; }'.

627 export interface ResponseEvents extends Podium {
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/hapi__hapi/index.d.ts:2357:43 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Listener' requires 1 type argument(s).

2357     removeListener(criteria: K, listener: Podium.Listener): this;
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/hapi__hapi/index.d.ts:2375:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'ServerEvents' incorrectly extends interface 'Podium'.
  The types returned by 'on(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'this'.
      'this' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'void'.

2375 export interface ServerEvents extends Podium {
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/hapi__hapi/index.d.ts:2441:44 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Listener' requires 1 type argument(s).

2441     removeListener(name: string, listener: Podium.Listener): Podium;
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/hapi__hapi/index.d.ts:4057:18 - error TS2709: Cannot use namespace 'Boom' as a type.

4057         (Error | Boom) |
                      ~~~~

node_modules/@types/hapi__inert/node_modules/@types/hapi__hapi/index.d.ts:260:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'RequestEvents' incorrectly extends interface 'Podium'.
  Types of property 'on' are incompatible.
    Type '{ (criteria: "peek", listener: PeekListener): void; (criteria: "finish" | "disconnect", listener: (data: undefined) => void): void; }' is not assignable to type '<Tcontext extends object = this>(criteria: string | CriteriaObject, listener: Listener<Tcontext>, context?: Tcontext) => this'.
      Types of parameters 'listener' and 'listener' are incompatible.
        Types of parameters 'tags' and 'encoding' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ [tag: string]: true; }'.

260 export interface RequestEvents extends Podium {
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/hapi__inert/node_modules/@types/hapi__hapi/index.d.ts:633:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'ResponseEvents' incorrectly extends interface 'Podium'.
  Types of property 'on' are incompatible.
    Type '{ (criteria: "peek", listener: PeekListener): void; (criteria: "finish", listener: (data: undefined) => void): void; }' is not assignable to type '<Tcontext extends object = this>(criteria: string | CriteriaObject, listener: Listener<Tcontext>, context?: Tcontext) => this'.
      Types of parameters 'listener' and 'listener' are incompatible.
        Types of parameters 'tags' and 'encoding' are incompatible.
          Type 'string' is not assignable to type '{ [tag: string]: true; }'.

633 export interface ResponseEvents extends Podium {
                     ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/hapi__inert/node_modules/@types/hapi__hapi/index.d.ts:2365:43 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Listener' requires 1 type argument(s).

2365     removeListener(criteria: K, listener: Podium.Listener): this;
                                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/hapi__inert/node_modules/@types/hapi__hapi/index.d.ts:2383:18 - error TS2430: Interface 'ServerEvents' incorrectly extends interface 'Podium'.
  The types returned by 'on(...)' are incompatible between these types.
    Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'this'.
      'this' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'void'.

2383 export interface ServerEvents extends Podium {
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/hapi__inert/node_modules/@types/hapi__hapi/index.d.ts:2449:44 - error TS2314: Generic type 'Listener' requires 1 type argument(s).

2449     removeListener(name: string, listener: Podium.Listener): Podium;
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Is there something wrong with a new version?? How can I fix this / are there version rollbacks that would work?

Current package.json file:

```
...
  "dependencies": {
    "@hapi/hapi": "^20.1.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.7",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.6",
    "tslint": "^6.1.3",
    "typescript": "^4.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/hapi__hapi": "^20.0.6"
  }
...
```

Answer (score 1):

They are looking at it already; https://github.com/hapijs/hapi/issues/4240